# How to Fix Javascript Search Function in Spring Boot Application

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

This is my first post, so apologies if this is not done properly.

I'm currently working on a Javascript search function in my Spring Boot app and am unable to figure out why it's not producing search results.

I've searched the interwebs to find something that might help, but have not found anything useful.

I've tried looking at the controller as well as the Javascript, but I'm still pretty new, so I can't seem to put my finger on what the problem might be.

Gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
        runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
        runtime('com.h2database:h2')
        testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    }
```

Controller

```
    @RequestMapping(path = "/searchBy/{barcode}", method = GET)
    public String searchAllByBarcode(@PathVariable String barcode, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("foundItems", itemRepo.findAllByBarcode(barcode));
        return "find";
    }
```

Javascript:

```
searchItems
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const addItemButton = document.querySelector('#findItems');
    addItemButton.addEventListener('click',searchItems)
});

function searchItems(){
    const barcode = document.querySelector('#info_input').value
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                console.log(xhr);
                console.log(barcode);
            }
        }

    xhr.open('GET', '/searchBy/'+ barcode, true)
    xhr.send()
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <header class="header">
            <img class="main__logo" src="../images/wolf.png" />
            <div class="title">
                <h3>Search an Item!</h3>
            </div>
        </header>

        <div class="delete__item__list">
            <div>
                <form method="GET">
                    <label id="search_by" for="input">
                        <select>
                            <option value="0">Search Item By:</option>
                            <option value="1">Barcode:</option>
                            <option value="2">Quantity:</option>
                            <option value="3">Expiration Date:</option>
                            <option value="4">Name:</option>
                            <option value="5">Unit:</option>
                            <option value="6">Location:</option>
                            <option value="7">Description:</option>
                            <option value="8">Mercedes</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" name="input" maxlength="200" id="info_input" autofocus="true" required="true" />
                    <input type="submit" id="findItems" name="myButton" value="Search" />
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="item-list" th:each="item: ${foundItems}">
                <div th:id="'item-'+ ${item.id}">
                    <a th:href="@{'/item/'+${item.id}}" th:text="${'Barcode: ' + item.Barcode + ' Quantity: ' + item.Quantity + ' Expiration Date: ' + item.ExpirationDate + ' Name: ' + item.Name + ' Unit: ' + item.Unit + ' Location: ' + item.Location + ' Price: ' + item.Price + ' Description: ' + item.Description}"></a>
                    <button type="submit" class="deleteItem" th:attr="data-id=${item.id}" for="id" name="id">Remove</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <nav class="nav__bar">
            <a href="add">
                <button class="add_item_button">Add</button>
            </a>
            <a href="delete">
                <button class="delete_button">Delete</button>
            </a>
            <a href="/">
                <button class="home_button">Home</button>
            </a>
        </nav>

        <footer class="footer">
        </footer>
    </div>

</body>

<script src="/js/search.js"></script>
```

This should be pulling the data from the database and displaying an inventory item, but instead, it shows no results. I'm not sure if it's the Javascrpt, controller, html or all the above.

Please let me know if there is anything more that's needed and I'll be happy to provide.

Thank you in advance for all the help.

Comment: Can you see the request going over network in dev tools? Also, why don't you use `fetch` API since you are working with ES6?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @joseatchang . Still pretty new to this, but it seems like a request was sent. Also, I have no clue what fetch API is so I apologize for my ignorance.

Comment: This is the [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) docs, is a promise based api for fetching data, is less verbose that the plain `xmhlHttpRequest`. Also is your request returning any data? You can look into network tab in dev tools to find out.

Comment: Thanks for the link @joseatchang . Yes, I did take a look at the docs and I think I'll probably go that route. I did some searching on fetch and it seems a lot of folks use PHP to get it to return data from the server. I'll need to do more studying to get it done that way. Also, I did look at the network tab and it does not receive data from the server. So I think it might be the way I'm sending data to the server. If that's the case, I think I'll just study up on using fetch and go that route. Thanks again for all the help.